# Websocket on Android Device socket vs static ip

Tags: android, websocket

I have started a websocket server on a Android device. The server is started on socket ip and not the static ip that you see in the wifi connections.

I am unable to connect to this socket ip from outside the Android device and I get a connection refused error.

My question is:
1. Can I connect to this socket server from an external device using the socket ip of this Android device?
2. Is it possible to start the websocket connection using the static ip and not this socket ip?

Background:
So, this is for a POC(Proof of Concept) which requires a web socket server to be started on an Android device. Other external devices on the same wifi network should be able to connect to this websocket server and send messages to it. In order to accomplish this, I used an external library https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
The websocket server got successfully started using InetSocketAddress. I tried to change this to use the ip from my wifi connection instead, which resulted in the error: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address.

Comment: It is unclear why you would start a server on an ip. And what do you have in mind with static ip and sicket ip? Please give examples of such ips. An Android device mostly has no fixed ip.

Comment: I added a Background paragraph in my post.

Comment: You have not answered my questions.

Comment: `Other external devices should be able to connect ... ` you mean devices in the same wifi/lan network?

Comment: What is a POC ?

Comment: In order for the server to be accessible from other devices in the LAN, the socket must be listening to the wildcard ip(0.0.0.0). It is not a good practice to hardcode the ip. If you instantiate the server with the default constructor it should listen to the wildcard ip.